# In Python, I have a table with columns and lines; how do I count how many repetitions there are?

Tags: python, lines, counting, biopython

Specifically, I have a big set of letters in each line like TDYAVTAGSRVCIVTAGARQREGESRL (or bigger).

In columns, I would have the letters; A, E, G, V, T, S, etc...

I want that each position can tell me how much repetitions there are. Like, in for column A; how many A's are in that line.

This is for proteins (lines) and amino acids (columns) on Biopython, but it should be something working for any example and I would like to know how to make it. With or without Biopython. In the future, both. As of know, one would be useful :D

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! One thing we ask is that you try to solve your problem and post some code. Make an attempt and many people will be happy to help.

Comment: It's hard to tell if this is a biopython or general python probelm, but read this documentation for [Manipulating Alignments](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc74). If that or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python) don't answer you question, ask a new question... but provide a better/real example :)